# create linked server to Mysql Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, odbc

I've created an ODBC connection to my MySQL cPanel. I've made the settings in System DSN and when I press TEST Connection the message that returns is succesful. I've added the IP as a wildcard. Then I'm going in the SQL Server Management Studio to create the linked server. I fill up with the dates, I choose "Microsoft OLE  DB Provider for ODBC drivers", but when I press OK the following error is showing up:

> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do
>   you want to keep the linked server?
>
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"
>   for linked server "GRUPSAPTE". OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked
>   server "XXXXXXX" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Access
>   denied for user 'gsapte'@'XXXXXXXXXX' (using password: NO)".
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

I've created many linked servers for localhost but when I'm trying to create for my webserver it shows the error above. Do I have to make some changes to the webserver or some access things?

Any advise will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked that the IP address you are coming from is allowed for the login? When I have used MySQL in a hosted environment, the mysql server checks if the user who is requesting access is coming from a known\permitted IP address. Don't know if this is the problem, just one similar to what you are asking.